# Port Restricted NAT

Tags: nat

Здравствуйте.

Я написал клиент на `java` для ПК, который сначала отправляет данные на `STUN` сервер с помощью сокета и получает ответ, в котором указаны внешний ИП и Порт.

Также клиент определил, что у меня `Port Restricted NAT`. Затем клиент выдает мне локальный порт, который участвовал в обмене сокета со `STUN`.

Сокет убивается. Далее с помощью `gstreamer` открывается и слушается тот самый локальный порт, а клиент передает полученный со `STUNа` внешний ип и порт в `SDP` файле на сервер `Kurento`.

`Kurento` обрабатывает ответ и отправляет видеопоток на указанный в `SDP` файле ип и порт.

Далее я делаю `tcpdump` на сервере и вижу, что передача с сервера на клиентский внешний адрес проходит, но `wireshark` показывает, что никакие пакеты мне не приходят. Следовательно `gstreamer` не проигрывает поток.

**Вопрос:** Что не так я делаю?

**P.S:** проверял работы сервера и клиента в локальной сети, т.е. `STUN` не нужен, все работает передача есть и `gstreamer` проигрывает поток.